# Internet Explorer request to csv file stored in s3 hangs on Pending indefinitely

Tags: csv, internet-explorer, amazon-s3

I'm currently developing a web app which uploads attachments to s3 to store them for later retrieval. While other text and images are downloading/displaying just fine, requests to csv files lock up in PENDING when using Internet Explorer, which unfortunately is what our clients predominantly use. The only workaround I've found is adding the S3 bucket to the Trusted Sites list, but I can't enforce that every client does this, or does this properly.

Sending the following headers:

Content-Type:text/csv
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Disposition:attachment

Comment: Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages". Save changes.... The IE dev tool will now list blocked content, XSS, markup and security errors and warnings..retest your web application..Are you using HTTPS in your download link? Also see IE Options>Advanced tab, uncheck "Do not save encrypted files to disk"

Comment: Thanks for the tip Rob! I've enabled this option, but I don't see any new information. We are using https in our link. Here is what the link looks like, more or less, generated by the AWS SDK and sent to the client: _https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/directory/unique_file_name.csv?response-cache-control=no-cache&response-content-disposition=text%2Fcsv&response-content-type=text%2Fcsv&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-ALGORITHM&X-Amz-Credential=LONGSTRINGOFCHARACTERS%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20170810T144337Z&X-Amz-Expires=15&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=awssignaturestring_

Comment: Test Plan: Copy the request to your clipboard, then open a blank page in IE (about:blank). Shift focus to the new blank tab, and PIN the dev tool to the tab. Select the Network tab of the dev tool and make sure its turned on to record the requests and responses. In the IE address bar, paste the request from the clipboard in the address bar and navigate it(Enter).... the dev tool network tab should now list the request for the download and the server response. Copy and paste the dev tools' Network tabs' output. If you can provide a reproduction url with your questions.